# Why is TestFlight not respecting my TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY setting?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

In my Xcode project, under *General* > *Deployment Info* > *Devices*, I've set the targeted device to **iPhone**. However, when I archived and submitted to iTunesConnect TestFlight users, they can still receive invites on iPads and install it on iPads which the app was not designed for. I have verified that it should be iPhone only by checking on the package contents of the exact archive that was submitted via the Xcode organizer window by checking the archive's info.plist which shows `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1;` (iPhone). Why is TestFlight not respecting this setting?

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and my Deployment Target is 10.0.

Comment: All iPhone-only apps can be run on iPads. This has always been true. You can't prevent it. This has nothing to do with TestFlight.

Comment: So what is the point of that setting?

Comment: It's to indicate that your iPhone-only app doesn't use the full iPad screen. The iPhone-only app will run on the iPad but it runs in a "compatibility mode". Your iPhone-only app will run like it's on a 3.5" iPhone.